# How can I make ThinkVantage Power Manager recognize my battery?

Tags: battery, thinkpad

I bought a ThinkPad SL400 about a year and a half ago that came with Windows Vista and ThinkVantage Power Manager preinstalled. I had no problems with it at that time. I upgraded to Windows 7 last week, and still had no problems with the Power Manager.

But then I decided to do a clean install of 7, and now the Power Manager reports "No battery installed" even though nothing else has changed. The battery *is* recognized by both the ThinkVantage Toolbox console and the Windows 7 battery tray icon. They report that it's in decent condition, with 93% of the capacity it had when it was new. The actual performance of the battery doesn't seem to have changed.

Due to the clean install, I had to re-download Power Manager from Lenovo's website; I'm using v3.3. I don't know what version I was using before. Based on Google results, I tried a number of things, including

- uninstalling/reinstalling ThinkVantage Toolbox
- uninstalling/reinstalling ThinkVantage Power Manager
- Booting up with only AC power, shutting down, pressing the power button ten times and booting up with the battery snapped back in
- changing the power plan

None of these helped. How can I get Power Manager to recognize my battery again? I like having the charge percentage/time remaining indicator in my taskbar.

Comment: See my answer here...http://superuser.com/questions/190494/what-does-the-thinkpad-power-button-trick-do

Comment: @Moab, yeah, I saw that you answered my other question, but that doesn't help with this question. Unless you are suggesting that a full BIOS reset is the answer for this question; are you?

Comment: Its a possibility, maybe not an answer, that's why I posted it here as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. I was having what I thought was a separate problem with my built-in volume control buttons, so I reinstalled the driver for that (ATK Hotkey driver). When I rebooted, the battery gauge was working. I guess Power Manager has a hidden dependency on ATK Hotkey drivers, but I'm not about to poke at it now that things are working.

One caveat, of sorts: I downloaded the latest 32-bit Windows 7 driver for the volume buttons directly from Lenovo's website, but the volume display that comes up is still the old neon green one. I'm not sure how to get the nicer black-and-white one I saw after I upgraded Vista to 7 and before I clean-installed 7. It's probably not relevant, but then, that's what I thought about the volume buttons and the battery gauge before.

Comment: 3.11.001 seems to the latest version I have installed, through System Update.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the [ThinkPad Power Management driver](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-4gxpeg.html) installed?  That's the current version installed on my X200s.

You should check that site for all the relevant drivers and software for your particular model and OS, by entering your model number on the right hand side.  You should also run ThinkVantage System Update to get a few further updates.

Comment: Yeah, when I downloaded Power Manager, I got the download URL from inside ThinkVantage Toolbox. The drivers and the program were all provided. There are no other ThinkVantage components that need to be updated, for what that's worth. Thanks though.