# Laptop screen won't turn on

Tags: windows-xp, boot, laptop-display, compaq-laptop

Sometimes when I press the power button, the laptop screen won't turn on. After trying on/off a few times with power button, I give it a few hard punches on its back, and then it eventually turns on! Once it turns on, it goes fine.

I think there's some problem with power on/off button that is little hard to press to turn the computer on. Could it be something wrong with the power button, stopping the laptop to boot up?

I have also tried taking out the batteries, leaving the laptop unused for sometime and then trying to boot up, but this never worked for me.

Also, the sounds or keyboard doesn't work at all unless the display is turned on first.

Comment: Sounds like a strong issue of violence against computers here. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a loose connection in your display to me, you should bring this to the next service center to check and/or repair it. Also laptops don't like to be punched on the back, this may be the source of your issue.

Comment: And stop punching it before you do REAL damage. :)

Comment: Hah, yes. I had the same idea reading it just now.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the power, then take out the battery.

Hold the start button on your laptop for 20-30 seconds. Once that's done, continue with installing the battery again and power lead, then simply press start on your laptop, and voilà – this should work.

Comment: Ahh, [the magic ACPI trick](http://www.masnick.com/2007/09/07/the-secret-thinkpad-powerbutton-code-to-bring-dead-laptops-back-to-life/)?

Comment: The article that @JourneymanGeek links describes this trick as working for Lenovos and makes no mention of any other brand of computer. The tags in the question suggest this is an HP/Compaq laptop. Does this technique actually work for brands other than Lenovo?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/190494/what-does-the-thinkpad-power-button-trick-do there's a possibly different trick for it. I'd linked that at the time since while it might help, without context, this sounds quite similar to, and entirely not unlike chanting and sacrificing goats at the full moon to get your monitor running.