# Laptop won't boot, emits double beep at turning on

Tags: bios, troubleshooting, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

**TL;DR version:** what do these two long beeps, [7s long track](https://soundcloud.com/user-276006597-690891444/ptt-20190919-wa0000), emitted at boot mean? Laptop does not work past this point. Any solution?

**The whole story:**

When I try to boot, my Lenovo Thinkpad laptop emits two long beeps and nothing else happens. It's just stuck there, nothing shows in the screen.

Here is the [7s long track](https://soundcloud.com/user-276006597-690891444/ptt-20190919-wa0000).

Lenovo Thinkpads use Phoenix BIOS, but I only find 4 digits error codes.
This has happen before, every now and then, but right now it's 100% of the time. Also laptop is inoperable. In the past I also got a Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) and a PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA message.

I tried: Lenovo's tool for recognizing error codes (a sound encoded numerical code emitted by Lenovos when things go wrong), but these codes are emitted later in the boot process. That is, mine are from the BIOS.

Would buying new RAM solve the problem?

The laptop has one memory stick and two slots. Same result independently of where the RAM is inserted. Without any memory it emits three beeps like the beeps above.

I looked up at [this list](https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm), but nothing matches.

Comment: Beep codes can be specific to the model. Lenovo posts their Hardware Maintenance Manuals on their support site https://support.lenovo.com. Get the HMM for your specific model and look up the section "Beep Codes".

Comment: Could you try the [magic power button trick](https://superuser.com/questions/190494/what-does-the-thinkpad-power-button-trick-do)? The version I remember is leaving it plugged in, pressing down the power button, then unplugging power, holding the power button down, waiting ten seconds not letting go the power button, and then plugging the power back in...